# Need to read a file with multiple lines of integers into an array

Tags: c, file-io

I need to read a file of ints into an array in C. A sample of the file I need to read is below, though note the files this will process can have thousands or hundreds of thousands of lines.

```
127
234
97
8723
```

I've gotten the file open in C, read how many lines there are so I know how many spaces my array needs, but I can't seem to read/parse each line into the array.

```
FILE *file;
int N = 0;
char filePath[30];
char endFile;

printf("What file should be used?\n");
scanf("%s", filePath);

file = fopen(filePath, "r");

if(file == NULL) {
    printf("This file failed to open.\n");
    break;
}

for(endFile = getc(file); endFile!=EOF; endFile=getc(file))
    if(endFile == '\n') {
        N = N+1;
    }
int myArray[N];

while(fscanf(file, "%d\n", &a) != EOF) {
    fscanf(file, "%d\n", &a); // I'm not sure this line is needed... 
    printf("%d\n", a);
    M[i] = a;
}
```

From here, I need to read the file contents into myArray, with each line being the corresponding spot in the array (i.e. line zero is myArray[0], line one is myArray[1], etc.). I can't seem to find a way to do this, though I see several methods to do tab-delimited 2d arrays or csv multi-dimensional arrays.

Please also let me know if creating the array/determining the array size can be done in a better way than literally counting new-line characters...

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to first "count the number of lines".

The following code *cautiously* grows an array of integers (by increments of 10).

```
#define GROW 10
int *rec = NULL, nRec = 0, sz = 0;
while( fgets( buf, sizeof buf, ifp ) != NULL ) {
    if( nRec == sz ) {
        rec = realloc( rec, (nRec+GROW) * sizeof *rec );
        /*omitting test for failure */
        sz += GROW;
    }
    rec[ nRec++ ] = atoi( buf );
}
```

This shows what is possible.
Note that `realloc()` *can* fail, returning NULL... It's up to you to add a bit of code to handle that condition.

Further, some conventional thought is to double the size of the allocation when needed (because `realloc()` may not be 'cheap'.) You can decide if you want to grow the array in increments (of 1024?) or grow it exponentially.

Comment: Working through and adding this, just to confirm, buf represents a char array where fgets inserts the next line into, correct? Also, upon compiling, I'm getting an error on realloc(rec, nRec+GROW)*sizeof rec indicating invalid operands to binary * (have void * and long unsigned int) - any idea how to correct?

Comment: Yes, `buf` would be declared as a (16 byte?) char array into which lines are read one-by-one. The way you've typed the `realloc()` statement is botched... Try using copy/paste from the code given in the answer above...